# Get current site URL or picture URL from Picture Library

Tags: xslt, url, picture-library

I created an xsl file to change the appearence of the Picture Library.
As I had troubles to get the PictureURL I took the value of the "FileLeafRef" to get the filename of the picture. Than I use the site url and add the value of "FileLeafRef". It works fine for the current site but I would like to use the same style on different subsites with the same Picture Library. How can I insert the current siteURL into img src=" "...
I already tried the value of _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl but I don't get any value.
This is the code I'm using:

```
    <xsl:variable name="LinkToBook">
        <xsl:value-of select="@LinkToBook"/>    
    </xsl:variable>

<div class="bookimage">
<a href="{$LinkToBook}" target="_blank">
<img src="/sites/sitecollection/subsite/subsubsite/FeaturedBooks/{$FileLeafRef}" alt="{$FileLeafRef}" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</a>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using FileLeafRef use FileRef will work 
examlpe

```
<img src="{@FileRef}" alt="{$FileLeafRef}" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: I already tried this approach but I get always the following message:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID:266e1b9e-f2c8-30d8-c784-120f58a518b9

Comment: No I entered:
 <xsl:param name="WebUrl"/>
below the xsl:styelsheet and the error message doesn't show up but I get only an empty string

Comment: updated the answer